# Textarea moves parts of my page when made bigger

Tags: css, position, textarea

I'm coding a comment page on my website and it all works fine, but when you make it bigger part of my pages (notifications) move across the page. I've coded the text area to the position I wanted using position relative. Here is the css code I've use:....

```
#mainSection{
text-align:left;
margin-top:3px;
margin-bottom:50px;
margin-left:270px;
position:relative;
bottom:650px;
}
#mainSection .newPost{
width:500px;
height:125px;
}
```

Comment: can you make a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the user from resizing the textbox altogether:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```